# Formula to convert ticks to a date in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have a date of 635241312000000000 from table exported from sql. The date should be 1/1/2014. I need a formula in Excel that will convert it.

I have tried the following assuming that the date was stored in ticks:

=(((((635241312000000000/100000000)/365.25)/24)/60)/60). This gives me a date of 7/19/1900 which is wrong.

I have other dates to convert too, so I need a formula that will work in Excel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you are correct about it being a tick date. This particular one appears to be the number of 100ths of a nanosecond since 01/01/0000. To convert it you can use:

```
 =(G6*POWER(10, -7) / 60 / 60 / 24)-693593
```

The 693593 on the end is the number of days between the tick start date and the excel date-type start date.

Comment: If your Version of Excel uses ',' as Decimal-Separator you have to replace "POWER(10, -7)" with "POWER(10; -7)"

Answer (score 2):

A complete formula for date and time:

```
=TicksValueCellReference/864000000000-693593
```

Change the excel cell format to (date)time.

I found this solution and a great description [here](http://vovici.com/downloads/commhelp/3_0/bp_tr/tr/read_day_time.htm).

Answer (score -2):

You do no need any formula for this.You can do this by formatting cell to date.Right Click on cell->Format Cell->Number tab->Date->Ok.This is for windows system.